# Server error: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible that put .sql file on APP_CODE folder and read that with project at client side at published copy?

actually i have some .sql file in app_code folder. After publishing this project (there is no app_code folder but has a app_code.dll file) when try to read that file from client machine it gives some error . look on image
.[image]

and this is the path where i am trying to get the file  `string scriptDirectory = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Code\\AppVersion\\version310113\\");`

Comment: Show your work and exception message as a text, not as an image.

Comment: Show us a code how you are reading sql and then we can say

Comment: its a website project ,,, may be (based on some study) i think there is no way to put a .sql file inside app_code folder .. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx

Comment: place the file in a new folder like 'erp' and then try to access it. App_Code doesnt exist necessarily in website project